# Software compatibility Lubuntu vs. Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I would like to make my laptop dual-boot and install Windows and Lubuntu on it.

My primary concern is: Does Lubuntu have software compatibility issues? I mean does the software that work on Ubuntu work on Lubuntu too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LUbuntu and Ubuntu differ only in desktop environment and they are the same in all other aspects. Thus softwares compatible with Ubuntu are compatible with LUbuntu as well.